# Dynamically creating an blank iframe with https protocol

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, https, src

I have this follow situation:

```
var i = document.createElement("iframe");
i.src = "about:blank";
i.addEventListener("load", function(){
console.log(i.contentWindow.document.location.protocol);
}, false);
vars.b.appendChild(i);
```

I need `document.location.protocol` return `https:` or `http:` according to refer page but it is returning always `about`, I can't change this command `location.protocol` becouse it is a 3th-party who runs it so I need to figure out a way to this and returns what they want.

It has to be a pure javascript solution

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems the trick it to set the `<iframe>` `src` to the protocol of the page creating it.

```
var i = document.createElement("iframe");

i.src = document.location.protocol;

i.addEventListener("load", function() {
   console.log(i.contentWindow.document.location.protocol);
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(i);
```

Check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a8osacok/

Console is logging `https:` when this script is run on https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've tried it in a real situation and it will cause an infinity loop and this loop actually makes sense because src is the current url. Thank you for your answer but it didn't work "/